# How to get Spyder import the version of the module that is being shown in Anaconda navigator?

Tags: anaconda, spyder, python-typing

I have just installed Anaconda on my Windows PC to write Python code with Spyder, and I want to use type annotation `TypeAlias` from module `typing`. Since `TypeAlias` was introduced in version 3.10 of `typing`, I have installed that version from Anaconda, and the Anaconda navigator confirms that I have 3.10.0 installed:

[image]

This I can also check by printing the list of packages with `conda list` in the Terminal. Fine.
Going back to Spyder console, doing `import typing` and checking the module location, I get this:

[image]

The file `typing.py` that is being referred to is some pre-3.10 version of `typing` that does not define `TypeAlias`, so it cannot be the file that was copied when I installed `typing` from the Anaconda navigator.

I have searched around, but I cannot figure out how to get Spyder use another file for that module. What am I supposed to do to have Spyder use the version of the module that is shown in the Anaconda navigator instead of the outdated version that came with Anaconda on installation?

Comment: Did you install it while Spyder was running and in the same environment Spyder is installed and was launching? If that is the case, try restarting the console kernel or launching a new console from Spyder

Comment: @DanielAlthviz, I have just removed and reinstalled `typing` from Anaconda, leaving Spyder closed, but I am back to the same problem. How do I check (and possibly set) the environment in which Spyder runs?

Comment: Have you read `typing` package description? It's a **backport** for python 3.5 and below (all EOL). All non-EOL pythons (and even 3.5 and 3.6) have `typing` built-in module, [as per documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). You just need to uninstall `typing` package. `TypeAlias` was introduced in python3.10, not in `typing` backport of same version. Finally, to use modern features in older pythons (e.g. TypeAlias in 3.9), you should use `typing_extensions` - it's an external package by core team for this purpose.

Comment: I solved my problem removing both Spyder and Anaconda, and reinstalling Anaconda and then Spyder in a dedicated `conda` environment, as per Spyder's installation guide (https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/installation.html#installing-with-conda). The guide (https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/installation.html#anaconda-base) also warns that the Spyder that comes with Anaconda can be outdated. As a matter of fact, the Spyder in Anaconda's base environment was 5.2.2 with Python 3.8, while Spyder 5.4.0 and Python 3.10 are currently available.